# In how many ways can 10 different objects be distributed among 3 children of different ages such that each child receives at least ..

Tags: combinatorics

> In how many ways can 10 different objects be distributed among 3 children of different ages such that each child receives at least 2 and number of objects received is inversely proportional to age?

The last condition is very confusing. How is it possible to select number of objects according to ages if the ages are not known?

How should I do it?

Comment: That last condition is quite weird, I agree. Where did you get this problem?

Comment: Very hard to guess.  Maybe all they mean is that if $A$ is older than $B$, $A$ gets more than $B$.   But who knows?

Comment: Very strange wording to a question.  I suppose that since we are told that there are $10$ objects and the children are all different ages, that implies that they should be receiving different numbers of objects... the only way in which this can happen with them each receiving at least two would be if one of them received $2$, another received $3$ and the remaining received $5$...  but it sounds unanswerable if the number of objects had been anything different

Comment: Operating under that assumption... choose the $2$ objects to go to the oldest child... choose the $3$ objects from those remaining to go to the middle child, and the $5$ to go to the youngest child... this can be done in $\binom{10}{2,3,5}=\dfrac{10!}{2!3!5!}$ ways.  That is a rather heavy assumption though as to the interpretation of that last line which I am rather unhappy with.

Comment: @JMoravitz you seem to be correct, because your answer matches. I am bit confused on how you selected $2,3,5$

Comment: Because it is the only integer solution to $a+b+c=10$ subject to $2\leq a<b<c$

Comment: @JMoravitz may i ask which formula you used ie. $\binom{10}{2,3,5}$? I am aware about the distribution with identical objects but not so much about different objects. Is it a permutation of $n$ things out which $p,q,r$ are alike?

Comment: Yes, it is the "multinomial coefficient"